# Preventing a C++ library from linking, past an expiration date

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static-libraries

I need to prevent C++ static libraries from linking past the expiration date of a software evaluation period. How can I do that?

This should work with the most recent versions of the Visual C++ compiler (2012, 2010, ideally 2008). Support for more compilers would be a plus (Intel, gcc, game consoles compilers). Being able to pop a compiler warning a few days before the expiration date would also be a nice feature.

Comment: why would you not make a check in each library function instead when it is executed?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Because our clients are software developers, and I don't want them to accidentally release a product that will expire because they forgot to give us a check.

Comment: What exactly expires? I assume a license, software itself doesn't really expire. In that case a runtime check should be sufficient (I hope they at least run their program once before releasing it).

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about an evaluation license with a trial period. So let's say our client builds a release with an evaluation version of our libraries. They distribute it as is. Three weeks later they get tons of phone calls from angry buyers saying their product won't run and complains about an expired license. We get the blame.

Comment: Now we could enable this check for debug builds only, but a tired programmer could just decide to link against the release build to be able to keep working, commit that, and forget about it.

Comment: how is your fault exactly that they released software with an evaluation copy of a library with an expiry date on it? Perhaps you should make it clear in your library to contact the developers of the software, not the developers of the library

Comment: @TomTanner Well my fault would be in not implementing a proper expiration date check. I don't want to make my client's life more complicated by letting this kind of thing happen, I'd rather have no expiration date check at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linker has no support for performing this sort of check. You will need to come up with a better solution for dealing with the "evaluation period" expiring.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think I've seen middleware for games doing this. Thus my question.

Comment: Couldn't find any evidence, so I guess you're right, that's just not possible. Until somebody finds a way ;)

Comment: @Laurent The thing is that the "library" is a blob of bytes; the linker doesn't execute any parts of the code. It just links them, along with other parts, into one executable.

This means that you cannot prevent the linking from occuring. What you can do, however, is add code in the library that checks the date when the resulting executable file is executed and act accordingly.

Whether this meets your needs, I don't know. But absent linker support for such a feature (which, imo, would be a silly feature for a linker to support) it's not happening.

Comment: Sure, I know how a linker works, and I have no idea how this would be possible, it's just that I *thought* I had seen it in action. Thus my question, you never know, Microsoft could be supporting this for some reason. I wanted to make sure whether this was the case, or not. Sometimes things that sound stupid or impossible are actually quite real ;)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean. The library itself does not contain the evaluation period (at least not in a simple format). 
A dirty solution would be to write a script that renames the affect static library.. then could the compiler not link against it. 
As far as I remember supports VS (and for sure make) to run a script before compiling.